# Positive Elements in a C*algebra

Tags: operator-algebras, c-star-algebras, banach-algebras

Let A be a C$^*$-Algebra, $a\in A$. Why is $a\ge 0$ (a is called "positive") iff $\forall \varphi\in S(A): \varphi\ge0$? S(A) is the set of linear positive functional $\eta:A\to\mathbb{C}$ with $\|\eta\|=1$.
Maybe i have to use Gelfand-Naimark/continuous functional-calculus

Is this Theorem 3.4.3 in Murphy's book"C*-Algebras and Operator Theory"? Why $\|\eta\|=1$ is important?

Comment: It's not important.

Comment: i tried this too but i stuck on <= because we dont have that a is selfadjoint. Therefore we can not say that $\pi(a)$ is positive, where $\pi$ is the universal representation. I need help how to continue.

Answer (score 1):

If $\varphi(a)\geq0$ for all states $\varphi$, you can do the following:

Note that a state is selfadjoint, i.e. it maps selfadjoints to real numbers. This, because any selfadjoint is a difference of two positives.

Write $a=b+ic$ with $b,c$ selfadjoint. Then $\varphi(b)$ and $\varphi(c)$ are real. So
$\varphi(a)=\varphi(b)+i\varphi(c)$ is positive, which then shows that $\varphi(c)=0$. As $\varphi$ can be any state, we conclude that $c=0$. So $a$ is selfadjoint.

Now you can use the Gelfand representation to conclude that $a\geq0$.